# Rails 3 Distinct Join With Postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

Using Postgresql 9.1 and Rails 3.2.2. How would I return a collection of the last single `users_checkins` per venue for a given user?

I have tried

```
User.find(1)
  .users_checkins
  .joins(:venues_checkins)
  .merge(VenuesCheckin.select('DISTINCT(venues_checkins.venue_id)'))
```

but that does not retrieve any of the attributes for the `UsersCheckin`. My models are below.

```
class Venue
  has_many :venues_checkins
  has_many :users_checkins, through: :venues_checkins
end

class UsersCheckin
  #start:datetime
  #finish:datetime
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :venues_checkin
end

class VenuesCheckin
  belongs_to :venue
  has_many :users_checkins
end

class User
  has_many :users_checkins
  has_many :venues_checkins, through: :users_checkins
  has_many :venues, through: :users_checkins
end
```

**Update**

If a user has 3 users_checkins records for Venue A and 3 for Venue B, my collection should return 2 records with one record being the last created users_checkin from Venue A and the other record being the last created users_checkin from Venue B with the collection ordered by first record in the collection being which of those 2 records was created last. And I start with the user because I only want the users_checkins for the given user.

Comment: If you want the end result to be a collection of UsersCheckin then should that be your starting point? Could you clarify what you mean by "last single users_checkins per venue"?

Comment: If a user has 3 `users_checkins` records for `Venue A` and 3 for `Venue B`, my collection should return 2 records with one record being the last created `users_checkin` from `Venue A` and the other record being the last created `users_checkin` from `Venue B` with the collection ordered by first record in the collection being which of those 2 records was created last. And I start with the user because I only want the `users_checkins` for the given user.

Answer (score 1):

If you can write the SQL and get it to work in the psql prompt, make it into a custom method in the User class, and skip trying to wedge the custom query into the ORM.

Also, it sounds like you want a min/max qualifier in your query, rather than distinct.